# cloudera host with bad health during install

Tags: installation, cloudera, cloudera-manager

Trying again & again with all required steps completed but cluster Installation when install selected Parcels, always shows every host with bad health. setup never completed at full.

i am installing cm 5.5 on CentOS 6.7 using virtualbox.

The Error

> Host is in bad health  cm.feuni.edu
>
> Host is in bad health  dn1.feuni.edu
>
> Host is in bad health  dn2.feuni.edu
>
> Host is in bad health  nn1.feuni.edu
>
> Host is in bad health  nn2.feuni.edu
>
> Host is in bad health  rm.feuni.edu

above error are shown on step 6 where setup says

> The selected parcels are being downloaded and installed on all the hosts in the cluster

in previous step 5 all hosts were completed with heartbeat checks in the end

memory distributions
cm 8GB
all others with 1GB

i could not find proper answer anywhere else. What reason could be for the bad health?

Comment: Not sure what exactly the issue is?

Comment: Bad health issue is gone but i have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: Java is the issue. log showed java 1.6 was installed while i had oracle jdk 1.7 before i started setup. i did not select "install java" during setup. setup completed but my cluster is still not running. now error is 'Internal error while querying the Host Monitor'

Comment: if during setup i select option to install java then OpenJDk is installed by the setup. no need to select the option to install Java. i will try again.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it will help you...
For me, after a few days I struggled with it,
I found the log files (at )

It had a comment there is a mismatch of the guid, 
so I uninstalled everything from both machines (using the script they give,`/usr/share/cmf/uninstall-cloudera-manager.sh` , `yum remove 'cloudera-manager-*'` and deletion of every directory related to cloudera I found...)

and then removed the guid file:

```
rm /var/lib/cloudera-scm-agent/cm_guid
```

Afterwards I re-installed everything, and that fixed that issue for me...

I read online that there can be issues with the hostname and things like that, but I guess that if you get to this part of the installation, you already fixed all the domain/FDQN/hosname/hosts issues.
It saddens me there is no real manual/FAQ for this product.. :(

Good luck!

Comment: I always forget to do that step. I don't know why the cloudera uninstaller doesn't delete that, too.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. This is my solution:
First I edited `config.ini`

```
$ nano /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini
```

so that the hostname where the same as the command `$ hostname` returned.

then I restarted the agent and the server of cloudera:

```
$ service cloudera-scm-agent restart
$ service cloudera-scm-server restart
```

then in cloudera manager I deleted the cluster and added again. The wizard continued to run normally.